# How to execute string as batch script in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a string in PowerShell that I want to have executed as a batch script.

Something like:

```
cmd /c $batch_script
```

I am working with a giant cluster%!&$ software suite called Oracle Hyperion (with which most knowledge of how it operates appears to be lost - even within Oracle), so the reasons I want to do this are complex and require specific knowledge to understand, so I really just want to know if this is possible or not.

Comment: That depends on what that string actually is. If it's the path to a batch script then yes, you can run a batch script from PowerShell. You shouldn't even need the `cmd /c` for that. The call operator (`&`) should suffice. If it's a batch command or sequence of batch commands it's probably still possible, but might get really complicated really fast.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a .bat file with & and then path to the bat file.

```
& D:\BatScripts\Example.bat
```

You can then also pipe that info to a string and assign it to a variable to compare against expected output etc.

```
$batOutput = & D:\BatScripts\Example.bat | Out-String
if($batOutput -like '*The operation completed successfully.*'){
    Write-Host ("Job Complete")
} else{
    Write-Host ("Job Failed")
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks for trying to help but this is not what was asked

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but for anyone searching for the answer - this might work.  Still somewhat new to PS myself, but it appears you can execute EXE files just by typing them in.  But SET is an internal BATCH command, not an executable file.  So executing CMD, and passing it SET, seems to work.

```
    $Cmd = "SET"
    CMD.EXE /C "$Cmd"
```

You should be able to build any string you want in the $Cmd variable and execute it. Not sure if the quotes around $Cmd are actually seen by CMD.EXE, so you may run into some issues where you have add quotes into the string.